# Settings in Sharedpreferences gone after I an app update with adb install -r

Tags: android, adb

There is something in my feature branch that stops the app updating without losing settings but I can't find out what.

When I do 'adb install -r app.apk' all the settings are gone, as if I uninstalled and installed again.

The issue is not with ADB, i also tried this on BB UEM app.

The latest version of the app contains a feature which includes quiet a lot of change including new services/permission/dependencies etc

I have tried playing with the version codes and version names, like keeping them the same and making sure the latest app has a higher version code and name, but it made no difference.

Any idea what it could be that's causing the app to reset?

Comment: Been years since I did Android dev, but I had issues with SharedPrefs not saving at one point, though the situation was different. Maybe [my question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500236/sharedpreferences-will-not-save-load-in-preferenceactivity) will be helpful?

Comment: @Reed thanks for that.btherebare a lot of good suggestions there but not anything that would work my problem