# when use getDefaultSharedPreferences and getSharedPreferences

Tags: android

I just curious. There are 3 method:

```
1. getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(String PrefName);

2. PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)

3. Context.getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)
```

As I know, the third method is only used when the first method is used, right?
But with 3 method we also use `addPreferencesFromResource(int resID)`;
so, what is the difference? When can we use one of these method?
Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Let's go one step at a time:

1. `setSharedPreferencesName()` is method that allows to set the name of the preference group for later use. This is helpful for example when using the helper class of 
   *PreferencesActivity* before loading a preferences from XML resource file by calling  `addPreferencesFromResource()`. It is therefore not as common as the other 2 methods you mentioned above.
2. `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` uses a default name, usually stored as /data/data/com.package.name/shared_prefs/com.package.name_preferences.xml.
   It is commonly used. Note that this default is set *per application*.

   The alternative method - `getSharedPreferences()` requires to indicate a specific preference (file) name and an operation mode.
3. As appears also in [another answer about shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310080/978329),
   `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` in fact uses Context.getSharedPreferences, so the result is the same, but without the flexbility to split to multiple preference files, that is offered by `getSharedPreferences()`. Sharing the preferences between apps using 
   a `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` operation indicator is also something possible using `getSharedPreferences()`, but is rarely used.

IMHO, *getDefaultSharedPreferences()* can be safely used without going into the confusion of multiple preference file names that are prone to typos and confusion.

If someone knows of a good reason to use *getSharedPreferences()* and not *getDefaultSharedPreferences()*, please let me know by commenting here.

Comment: The main differences is (getDefaultSharedPreferences vs getSharedPreferences ) -- if you want change the any preference value in getDefaultSharedPreferences then use the apply() instead of commit(), If you use the commit in getDefaultSharedPreferences it's never apply the any effect.... I have spend more then 2 hrs.. for this silly mistake, So I just mention here.

Answer (score 2):

`getDefaultSharedPreferences()` uses a default preference-file name like `"com.example.something_preferences"`. This default is set per application, so all activities in the same app context can access it easily as in the following example:

```
SharedPreferences spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (spref.contains("email")) {
     String sEmailAddr = spref.getString("email", "");
}
```

The preferences are usually stored at /data/data/com.package.name/shared_prefs/com.package.name_preferences.xml

**getSharedPreference is the best way because using getDefaultSharedPreferences has some flaws**

1. Actualy `getDefaultSharedPreferences` doesn't work correct on some
   devices when build with targer api 13
2. Starting app from shortcut and from menu gives me different
   `DefaultSharedPreferences`. After removing DefaultSharedPreferences
   from my code - it works perfect. I can't just say: people dont make
   shrotcuts, so I had to change code

This [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786172/android-getdefaultsharedpreferences) may also help