# Android getDefaultSharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My code is:

```
final String eulaKey = "mykey";
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean hasBeenShown = prefs.getBoolean(eulaKey, false);
```

Always returns different values depending on os version. Tested in 2.2, 2.3.4, 3.2, 4.0.3 - returns correct value. But for device Zte blade with 2.3.7 with CianogenMod 7.1 - result is always false. I suppose default value for getBoolean.

Here is code writing boolean:

```
final String eulaKey = "mykey";
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
editor.commit();
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Update:
Comparing my current code with my previous version of code - there is no difference in code.
Only difference is in manifest: code works Ok  with minVersion=8 and targetVersion=8
Now I'm compiling with minversion=8 and target=13 /because of Admob/.
Maybe some APIs changed, but I found nothing on this.

SOLUTION:
-Starting app from shortcut and from menu gives me different DefaultSharedPreferences. After removing DefaultSharedPreferences from my code - it works perfect. I can't just say: people don't make shortcuts, so I had to change code.

Comment: It's not unheard of for some devices to randomly lose  SharedPreferences data. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359 for an example.

Comment: Is this info related only to getDefaultSharedPreferences? Do you know same issues about getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); ?

Comment: try with getSharedPreferences than the default one. It works fine

Comment: in getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this); say warning and deprecated!what we do now?

Comment: Hmm... it seems like OS versions mess up with package names. See my Q&A related to the difference of those functions of shared-prefs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37953072/4410376

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
final String eulaKey = "mykey";
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
editor.commit();
```

in which case you can specify your own preferences file name (myAppPrefs) and can control access persmission to it. Other operating modes include:

- MODE_WORLD_READABLE
- MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
- MODE_MULTI_PROCESS

Comment: Starting app from shortcut and from menu gives me different DefaultSharedPreferences. After removing DefaultSharedPreferences from my code - it works perfect. I can't just say: people dont make shrotcuts, so I had to change code.

Answer (score 6):

If you've upgraded to targeting API 30 drop this in your gradle dependencies:

`implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.0.0'//For Kotlin` Projects

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'//For Java Projects
```

After re-synching Gradle change all of your imports from

```
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
```

To

```
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
```