# Shared Preferences and Preference Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-switch

Here are my questions:

1. How can I get the value of a switch preference?
2. Are things inside a preference fragment already a shared preference?
3. If so, how can I access shared preferences from a preference fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** To get the value of a switch:

```
CompoundButton cb = (CompoundButton)view.findViewById(R.id.myswitch);

if(cb.isChecked())
    cb.setChecked(false);
else
    cb.setChecked(true);
```

Reference: [Toggle Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

**2.** Yes, the elements in a `PreferenceFragment` are automatically stored.

**3.** To get the `SharedPreference` object of a `PreferenceFragment`, use:

```
getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)
```

Comment: no it isn't. is a compound button the same with a switch preference?

Comment: and i don't see any id element for preference fragments.

Comment: yes it is. Have you tried the code ?? I've used this in a number of projects

Comment: sorry. i don't know how to get there from here, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html

Comment: sure, if you'd upvote my question. also, can you help me with this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028707/service-broadcast-receiver-logs-more-than-expected

Answer (score 0):

This is an amazing example on how to make a PreferenceFragment:
http://android-er.blogspot.hu/2012/07/example-of-using-preferencefragment.html

Basically the way it works is that you define the preferences with their types and keys. The preference fragment stores its data in the SharedPreferences, which you obtain via [Android getDefaultSharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786172/android-getdefaultsharedpreferences) , and edit its values and obtain them from an Editor.

In a Preference Fragment, you automatically have the data of the prefs linked between the Fragment and the SharedPrefs.

Also look at this example code: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-shared-preferences-example_12.html