# In App Purchase Remove Ads using boolean

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement Android in app purchase remove ads function. Under my class, I put `private boolean isAdsDisabled;` and under `onCreate`, I put

```
if (isAdsDisabled) {
            AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
```

This is my `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener`

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                          Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle error
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                removeAds();
            }

        }
    };
```

My `removeAds()`

```
private void removeAds() {
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isAdsDisabled = true;
    }
```

After successful purchase, I manage to hide the ads. However the problem after I restart my app, the ads reappear. Seem like it can't save the boolean `isAdsDisabled = true`. How to fix this?

Comment: you should permanent save value of in app purchase in db or server then further use because Boolean is temporary.It can not access after destroy the activity

Comment: But there is someone managed to do it using boolean:
http://www.tutorialsface.com/2016/05/implementing-remove-ads-in-app-purchases-in-android-tutorial-example/

Comment: but just think from where you get value of boolean after destroy the activity. It is not save any where

Comment: Use a shared preference for this. Save the Boolean as true  as soon as you purchase the sku. And retrieve the preference value on oncreate .

Here is an eg:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786172/android-getdefaultsharedpreferences

Comment: @user2872856 In the link you have provided.It will always return from this line if (result.isFailure())  and the error will be "you already own this item" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this using `SharedPreferences`.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        boolean isAdsDisabled = settings.getBoolean("isAdsDisabled", false);

        if (isAdsDisabled) {
            AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
```

And my `removeAds()`

```
private void removeAds() {
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isAdsDisabled", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
```