# String cannot be cast to Integer error

Tags: android, types

This error appears when I tring get value from preference:

```
public static final String PREF_KEY_INTERVAL = "pref_key_interval";
settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
int curInterval =  settings.getInt(PREF_KEY_INTERVAL, 1);
```

It is also worth noting that app works correctly on emulated device but crashes on real one. I already checked returned type several times. What is the clue or my IDE just goes mad?

preference xml:

```
<Preference
    android:key="pref_key_interval"
    android:title="@string/pref_key_interval_title"
    android:summary="@string/pref_key_interval_summary"
    android:defaultValue="5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:defaultValue = "5"` is a `String`. So you're casting a `String` to an `integer`. Try this

```
int curInterval =  Integer.parseInt(settings.getString(PREF_KEY_INTERVAL, "1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use DefaultSharedPreferences.

```
final String eulaKey = "mykey";
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean(eulaKey, true);
editor.commit();
```

from [Android getDefaultSharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786172/android-getdefaultsharedpreferences)