# Shared Preferences is read as the wrong type

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm reading SharedPreferences in my app at startup, and after a few runs it will crash and tell me that I'm trying to cast from a String to a Boolean. Below is the code that I use to read and write this value.

```
// Checks if the realm has been copied to the device, and copies it if it hasn't.
private void copyRealm() {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if (!sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_copied), false)) {
        // Copy the realm to device.
        final String path = copyBundledRealmFile(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.realm), getString(R.string.realm_name));

        // Save the path of the realm, and that the realm has been copied.
        sharedPreferences.edit()
                .putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_copied), true)
                .putString(getString(R.string.pref_path), path)
                .apply();
    }
}
```

The two strange things are that it doesn't start happening for a few builds, and so far it has only happened on a simulator. I haven't been able to check a physical device yet, but I've also been running this code without change for several months and had no trouble.

Why would I be getting this message?

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:293)`?

Comment: What's the string in the resource `pref_copied`?

Comment: @kabuko "Realm is copied"

Comment: Seems reasonable enough, is there any other code that changes your shared preferences at all?

Comment: Nope, that's the only time it's read or written to.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this question [Android getDefaultSharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786172/android-getdefaultsharedpreferences).

It seems it's a better idea to just use

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or

```
SharedPreferences references1=getSharedPreferences("some_name",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

instead of using

```
SharedPreferences preferences= getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

From the documentation:

> getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) retrieves a SharedPreferences object for
>   accessing preferences that are private to this activity. This simply
>   calls the underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by
>   passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.

I regularly use one of these two approaches and had no problem of any kind so far.