# Android Context Change on update?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Native Android App in the Store. This App has its Settings stored in the SharedPreferences. Now I am working on an Update for the App. The Update is a Xamarin Cross-Platform App. App Name, Package Name, and those things are the same as in the Native App. But I can't get the values from SharedPreferences now. Did I make something wrong? I guess it's because of a different Application Context. But I don't know why.

Here is how the Native App is loading the Values:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
final Set<String> keySet = prefs.getAll().keySet();

for (final String key : keySet) {
    if (key.startsWith(DatabaseSetting.DATABASE_SETTING_KEY_PREFIX)) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

After updating the App I can not see any keys in the prefs.
C# Xamarin Code to also load these prefs:

```
ISharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.Context);
foreach (string key in sharedPrefs.All.Keys)
{
  if(key.StartsWith(DATABASE_SETTING_KEY_PREFIX))
}
```

The App was updated without uninstalling the old one. Just deployed the new one.

Comment: Could you share your detailed steps of Updating the app?

Comment: I install the App from store and then just start debugging the new one. The old gets replaced automatically.

Comment: By `start debugging`, you mean click the green triangle button in visual studio under debug mode?

Comment: Yes, thats what I do

Comment: I found out, that Android is removing the old App first, so the data is lost before the new app is starting. How can I simulate a real update process without removing the prefs?

Comment: visual studio will detect the installed app with the same packageName. And uninstall the existing App, if the previous app is different from the to be installed one. You can take a try to generate an APK file in VS and use `adb install -r` to try to update that app.

Comment: Okay, strange. I will try that. But the iOS update was possible from VS.

Comment: Tried it. But update fails every time. APK is damaged. But when the old is not installed it can install the APK

Comment: Tried release and debug versions

Comment: Then there will be no way to update from android native app to Xamarin.Android directly.

Comment: But when I upload it to Google Play the update will work?

Comment: I'm not sure of that, never tried that. Google Store will be responsible of install/uninstalling of your app at that time. You can have a try if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it giving you a nullpoint?
2. Are you storing app context (Android.App.Application.Context) or class context(Context)?
3. Are there any other exceptions thrown that you possibly aren't catching?

Comment: It's giving me just empty SharedPreferences. No Exceptions. Application.Context

Comment: @M.D. I'd suggest you check where you are passing the shared preference... if possible edit your question and add the point you are passing the shared preference

Comment: @M.D. ok try to see what this user did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786739/5251647) and see how they do it... i think that will help

Comment: Good point. But unfortunately I can not change the "old" Apps code. So I can not change the way it is saved.

Comment: @M.D. ok that makes it difficult... sorry I couldn't be of assistance