# PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences() vs getPreferences()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

and

```
getPreferences()
```

seem to retrieve different Preferences.

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(
                        "userWasAskedToEnableGps", false);
```

for me returns false,

```
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("userWasAskedToEnableGps", false);
```

returns true.

The Preference was written with an Editor like

```
Editor e = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); 
e.putBoolean (...);
e.commit();
```

How can I get the same Preferences outside of an Activity from the Context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From android github repo([1](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-sdk-4.4.2_r1/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L4517)), we can see that `getPreferences` does nothing other than invoking `getSharedPreferences` method with current class name.

```
public SharedPreferences getPreferences( int mode ) {
    return getSharedPreferences( getLocalClassName(), mode );
}
```

There is nothing limiting other activities/code from accessing the shared preference with appropriate class name. More importantly, I prefer **not** to use `getPreferences`, since that implies => never ever change the Activity name. If you change, then take care of the accessing shared preferences with explicit mentions to the earlier class name ( before upgrade ).

Answer (score 13):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

`getSharedPreferences()` - *Use this if you need multiple preferences files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter.*

`getPreferences()` - *Use this if you need only one preferences file for your Activity. Because this will be the only preferences file for your Activity, you don't supply a name.* **scope limited to activity where it is created**

So if you want the preference to be available in another activity or context, you have to use either of `getSharedPreferences()` or `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`

This [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences/6310080#6310080) explains you the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Context.getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with the same constant name and it will give you the same preferences in any point of your app.