# Values Aren't saved in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, screen

I've created a shared preference screen on android to receive info from the shared preference screen to the main screen, every thing is working fine, but the the values in the preference screen aren't saved , and every time I must open the shared preference screen and type the info manualy ... any suggestions to auto save the preferences?

this is the shared perefrence code:

```
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SavePreff);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String ID_NO = ID_NUMBER.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences prefsExample = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefsExample.edit();
            editor.putString("idNumber", ID_NO);

            if (rd1.isChecked())

                editor.putString("Network", "STC");

            else if (rd2.isChecked())
                editor.putString("Network", "Mobily");

            else 
                editor.putString("Network", "Zain");

            editor.commit();

            Intent i = new Intent(SharedPref.this , MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

and this is the main activity screen that I'm using the info from it :

```
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences example = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);
            String ID_NUM = example.getString("idNumber", "123432");
            String NETWORK = example.getString("Network", "STC");
            String called_num = "";

            if (NETWORK.equals("Mobily"))
                called_num = "*1400*" + CODE_CHARGE.getText().toString() + "*"+ ID_NUM+ Uri.encode("#");
            else if (NETWORK.equals("STC"))
                called_num = "*155*" + CODE_CHARGE.getText().toString() + "*"+ ID_NUM+ Uri.encode("#");
            else if (NETWORK.equals("Zain"))
                called_num = "*141*" + ID_NUM + "*"
                        + CODE_CHARGE.getText().toString()+ Uri.encode("#");

            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL");
            Uri data = Uri.parse("tel:" + called_num);
            i.setData(data);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to use the default Shared Preferences, this solved it for me.

Comment: any codes suggestions ?

Comment: any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences are like these two

```
//example1 for Shared Prefs that lasts forever
example1= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);   
//example for Shared Prefs that lasts only just once each time program is running
example2= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In your code, use

```
 example1= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Hope this works for you..

Comment: i have no getDefaultSharedPreferences(); in the options and I get error when writing it , and its not allow to use context

Comment: You please define the Shared preferences after `setContentView` in your `onCreate()`..So please move the code to `onCreate()`

Comment: SharedPreferences prefsExample = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); is not working

Comment: The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(SharedPref) is undefined for the type SharedPref

Comment: it's too long , but could you give me a link for a solution or any project ??

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204708/preferencemanager-getdefaultsharedpreferences-vs-getpreferences) and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences) too..

Comment: Or else check these [links](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)&oq=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)&aqs=chrome..69i57.1646j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)