# How can i add multiple entries in a shared prefrences file

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Can you please tell me how can i use shared prefrences to write multiple entries in a shared prefrences file.Like if i want to add multiple names in the shared pref file
i am using the following code but each time i click on submit button it overrides the previous entry.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{           
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("users", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorUser = settings.edit();
    editorUser.putString("user", editUser.getText().toString());
    editorUser.commit();
}
```

Comment: You can only save one value associated with a particular key.

Comment: how can we save more than one?

Comment: Well the idea is simple.Use different key to save different value.

Comment: are you using the same EditText to save very user?

Comment: yes.i am using the same one

Comment: why u don't try to create multiple files in the shared pref to save the data of multiple users

Comment: i am allowing users to register themselves when they enter their name and click on button they get registered and then they can login

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use different keys, e.g.:

```
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("users", 0);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editorUser = settings.edit();
            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) 
                 editorUser.putString("user" + i, users.get(i));

            editorUser.commit();
```

Comment: what if i have n numbers of users

Comment: this might produce trouble as the sharedPref saves it persistent and there is no check if user exists already.

Comment: Szymom answer is correct, if you use shared preference for saving datas. Try to use DB, this is an another way to store datas and to check if the user exists already or not

Comment: Shared preferences are meant to store simple stuff without much complications. Also, the question wasn't about not overwriting the same key (at least that's how I understood it).

Comment: I am a newbie in android.could you let me know how to use different keys to store values.anyone plz.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this

Go through with these 2 URL this will help you

[**vogella.**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)

[**mobile.tutsplus.com**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/)

**Save**

```
 public void saveInformation(String username,String password) {
        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("shared", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.putString("password", password);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

**Load**

```
private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
    String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");

   }
```

**Edit**

```
 private void editDate(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("username", mSaved.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("selection-start", mSaved.getSelectionStart());
    editor.putInt("selection-end", mSaved.getSelectionEnd());
    editor.commit();
   }
```

To save multiple users data in will suggest you to create multiple files for each user and then save it in shared pref

Just go through with the diffrence between **getDefaultSharedPreferences**  and **getSharedPreferences**  from here  [**Diffrence Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences)

Comment: thx for reply Gaurav but i am not getting it,it seems like same code written in different way.

Comment: it's a function just pass the parameter to this function .and add all like i have done for username and password. and call it from where u want to save the data

Comment: @user2783369 see i have updated my answer if u need any help let me know

Comment: i am trying to use this code but it is not working for me Gaurav:(

Comment: what actually u need to save the details of multiple users in shared pref i am updating my answer sure it will help you

Comment: how can this save different users and their passwords?  you need some kind of list to achieve it like this here.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing that overriding issue because you are using the same shared preference `key` each time to save the `value`. Assuming that you are using the same `EditText` for multiple entries, I guess the following snippet will do the trick.

```
counter=0;
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  settings = getSharedPreferences("users", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editorUser = settings.edit();
                    editorUser.putString("user"+counter, Edittext.getText().toString());
                    editorUser.commit();
                    counter++;
                    Edittext.setText("");
            }
        });
        show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
                {
                    Log.i("User "+i, ""+settings.getString("user"+i, ""));
                }
            }
        });
```

Here, I used the `show` button `OnClickListner` just to check for the multiple entries through `EditText`. But here I would like to suggest you to go for SQLite DB if you really wish to store multiple user info.