# One can use getDefaultSharedPreferences and getSharedPreferences(nome,mode) in the same app?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm maintaining an app that uses Shared Preferences.

Normal settings are got from getDefaultSharedPreferences. I would like to store another set of preferentes (user session info, completely unrelated with the other settings), using getSharedPreferences.

If I do that, there's any chance of one cause interference on another?

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Difference between getDefaultSharedPreferences and getSharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I do that, there's any chance of one cause interference on another?

no there is not such a thing. They are stored in two different xml files (unless you are so lucky to guess the default name, `context.getPackageName() + "_preferences"`).