# Android - SharedPreferences not working?

Tags: android

Here's the code where I get to have the `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
Button b;
EditText et;
TextView tv;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
String rfid, getPref;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);




    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginnext);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rfid);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);



    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity2.this, "",
                    "Validating user...", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    login();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

void login(){
    try{

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(getPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://usamobileapp.pe.hu/webservice/check.php");

        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et.getText().toString().trim()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    editor.putString("rfid" ,rfid);
                    editor.commit();

                }
            });

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity3Activity.class));
        }else{
            showAlert();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is where I'd like the get the Registration ID entered by the user and use it in all activities of the app.

Here is the code to check whether I get to have the `SharedPreferences` correctly. It displays it through I text view. I wonder why it would not show up. Did I do the `SharePreferences` correctly?

```
public class ViewGradesActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView viewPref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_grades);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String get = settings.getString("rfid", "");

    viewPref = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    viewPref.setText(get);

}
```

}

By the way, the code above is from another class.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You need to get the SharedPreferences in your ViewGradesActivity the same way your getting it in your MainActivity2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving this error because you are writing to a different `SharedPreferences` than you are reading from. If you are using default `SharedPreferences`, make sure you read and write to the default preferences.

```
// Read the String from SharedPreferences
String awesomeString = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("key", "");

// Write the String to SharedPreferences
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        .edit().putString("key", awesomeString).commit();
```

Comment: In this case, it is a reference to your `Activity`. Use either "this" or "ViewGradesActivity.this".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you put any value in rfid? Here

```
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    editor.putString("rfid" ,rfid);
                    editor.commit();

                }
```

I think `rfid` is `null`. I did not find any place where you are initializing it.

Put `rfid` in toast or log it and you will see.

And as everybody else say you have to use default shared preferences in both classes. Here you can find why [Difference between getDefaultSharedPreferences and getSharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't read and write the preferences in the same preference file.

To write you use:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(getPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To read you use:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

So you write you preferences in a file `getPref` (which is null according to your code, don't you get any error?) but you read your preferences in the default file provided by the Android API.