# Get SharedPreferenes from another activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am trying to get the SharedPreferenes that I have saved in two different activities into my SMS activity. They are both saved as Strings.

For the phone number, it is saved as a string and is just directly inside of the onActivityResult (because it is getting the phone number out of the contact list)

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                        //---save the values in the EditText view to preferences---
                        editor.putString("phoneNumber", phn_no);

                        //---saves the values---
                       editor.commit();

                        phoneN.setText(phn_no);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For the message, it has a method.

```
public void AddMessage() {
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                    //---save the values in the EditText view to preferences---
                    //editor.putInt("id", Integer.parseInt(e_id.getText().toString()));
                    editor.putString("message", editMessage.getText().toString());

                    //---saves the values---
                    editor.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

    );
}
```

I have tried doing this:

```
SharedPreferences settings =    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                        String phoneNum = settings.getString("phoneNumber", "");
                        String message = settings.getString("message", "");
                        Log.d(TAG, message.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, phoneNum.toString());
```

But it is not saved in this. Might have did it wrong...

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT

also tried to do this:

```
SharedPreferences spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                        if (spref.contains("message")) {
                            String mes = spref.getString("message", "");
                            Log.d(TAG, mes)
;                            }
                        if(spref.contains("phoneNumber")){
                            String phn = spref.getString("phoneN", "");
                            Log.d(TAG,phn);
                        }
```

it did not work. Nothing has showed up in the Log.

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: make a change last section to context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences

Comment: Nabin - I am getting Strings that I have already saved in the SharedPreferences. shijil - what is "context"

Comment: @isabella http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android

Comment: Please update your code with the changes you've made, and put the log results in the question as well if you're still having problems.

Comment: @shijil oh okay you meant this "Context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);" but it also didn't work the error it gave was " Non-Static method 'getSharedPreferences()' cannot be referenced from static context

Comment: That's not what he meant, when you call `getSharedPreferences()` it's the same thing as calling `this.getSharedPreferences()`, where `this` is the context.  It looks like you are still writing to different prefs than you are reading from.

Comment: Because I am trying to understand how to get the prefs. I have them saved in two different activities. I was trying to call all the prefs from one of the activities but that didn't work. Should I just save the all the prefs in each activity in theSharedPreferences spref ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to store something like .... in Preferences. so do like 
first to create Common class like..

```
package com.ibl.commonClass;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

import android.net.NetworkInfo;

import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import android.view.View;


public class Global {

public SharedPreferences SharedPref;
Editor Editor;
Context context;
public Global(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    SharedPref = this.context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

public static void setPreferenceString(Context c, String pref, String val) {
    Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit();
    e.putString(pref, val);
    e.commit();
}

public static void setPreferenceInt(Context c, String pref, int val) {
    Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit();
    e.putInt(pref, val);
    e.commit();
}

public static void setPreferenceLong(Context c, String pref, Long val) {
    Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit();
    e.putLong(pref, val);
    e.commit();
}

public static void setPreferenceBoolean(Context c, String pref, Boolean val) {
    Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit();
    e.putBoolean(pref, val);
    e.commit();
}

public static void clearPreferenceUid(Context c, String pref) {
    Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit();
    e.remove(pref);
    e.commit();
}

public static boolean getPreferenceBoolean(Context c, String pref,
        Boolean val) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).getBoolean(
            pref, val);
}

public static int getPreferenceInt(Context c, String pref, int val) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).getInt(pref,
            val);
}

public static Long getPreferenceLong(Context c, String pref, Long val) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).getLong(pref,
            val);
}

public static String getPreferenceString(Context c, String pref, String val) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).getString(pref,
            val);
}

}
```

now you use any activity to set preferences like

```
 String mEmail;
```

this i get when user login in application

```
 mEmail = obj.getString("email");
Global.setPreferenceString(getApplicationContext(), "email",mEmail);
```

and like this you get Preferences

```
 Global.getPreferenceString(getActivity(), "email", "");
```

in Activity to use `"getApplicationContext()"` and in fragment "`getActivity()`"
Thanks & Regards

Comment: THANK YOU this worked! and with the help of @PM25793

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line

```
SharedPreferences settings =    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

use

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Changing that line still didn't work. the Log: "The Goods:﹕ [ 04-30 23:04:03.225  3176: 3176 D/The Goods:  ]"

Comment: Make sure you are adding values to it otherwise it will return default value ""

Answer (score 0):

Use this while accesing sharedprefrence istead of

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

// Use this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing something, I don't know what but **try do keep the SharedPreference name in a constant file** and make it final. Because it is possible that you save the values in a different SharedPreference and get from different. For example:--

```
/*
**Declare SharedPreference name as a final
*/
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MY_PREFS";
```

Now use this variable to get a SharedPreferences from anywhere.  For example:--

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreference(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```