# setrepeating alarmmanager with changing values

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Can we use setrepeating in alarmmanager with changing values? For instance,

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*14, pi);
```

sets the interval to be 14 days. But if my phone restarts the alarm resets from start. I can write the value for the next alarm to file on SD card, but i am confused that how to call that value in alarm manager?

---------------------------------UPDATE 2-----------------------

The updated logic is:
In broadcast receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

In Main Activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
long nextTime = prefs.getLong("timerval", 0);
Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, ishintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTime,
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*14, pi);
```

While, MyService is a service that start my actual activity, and in that activity, when user clicks "Submit" button, after saving the data, the next timer fire time is calculated and saved like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
Long nextint = System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000;
editor.putLong("timerval", nextint );
editor.commit();
```

But the issue is that on phone restart app still pop ups. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use a file on the SD card for that, use `SharedPreferences`, where you can store data types like booleans or integers.

Comment: yes, thats what I plan to use, but I am lost in how to use that value in alarmmanager. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure that if you use `getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)`, you don't also use `getDefaultSharedPreferences`. They need to be the same. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to set the alarm to the value stored in `SharedPreferences` after the phone restarts. In that case you will need to receive the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent (see [this relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290141/android-broadcastreceiver-on-startup) -- you need to set up a `BroadcastReceiver`). Then to set your alarm:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
long nextTime = prefs.getLong("timerval", 0);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTime,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*14, pi);
```

Your call to `AlarmManager.setRepeating(...)` has the arguments wrong. Note the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). The arguments to `setRepeating` are (in order): the type, the next time to fire, the interval between alarms [after the first alarm fires], then the pending intent. You are currently setting the time to fire to be `0ms`, which I think is not what you want. Instead, you want it to be the time from your `SharedPreferences`.

**EDIT:** It seems that you are using the `BroadcastReceiver` incorrectly. Right now you are using it to start the `MainActivity` (which is why it pops up when the phone restarts) but what you need is for it to set the `AlarmManager`. So create a new `Service`, and in that service, set the `AlarmManager`, and in your `BroadcastReceiver`, instead of calling `startActivity()` on your `MainActivity`, call `startService()` on your new `Service`. (Remember to end the service after the `AlarmManager` is set)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I am using broadcast receiver to restart the service that starts my "main activity". Just to double check I updated my logic above. Can you please comment? Also, I am confused about alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTime, .... please see my change in this part.

Comment: Thank you, I realized my mistake. Let me update my code.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, can you see my updated question? I am sure that the value from shared preference is correct, but on phone's restart app shows up immediately. Your suggestion will be really helpful

Comment: Can you restate what it is that you're trying to do? The reason that your app is popping up when the phone restarts is because in your `BroadcastReceiver` you are starting `MainActivity.class` which causes the activity's user interface to pop up.

Comment: Primarily I have a questionnaire app, that will pop up every 2 weeks. For that, my "broadcast receiver" starts "Main Activity" which does nothing but uses "alarm manager" to start "MyService". "MyService" registers a WiFi receiver for data transfer and also it startsup the "QuestionsActivity". Now the issue is that whenever I restart the phone, "QuestionsActivity" pops up. I double checked the timer value, that seems correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me, but the issue is that instead of blank "Main Activity" it pops up "QuestionsActivity". Also, I can see the design bug, pls suggest any changes.

Comment: I updated my answer. Don't use the BroadcastReceiver to start an Activity to set the alarm, use the BR to start a service instead.