# Retrieving SharedPreferences Values not working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Here's where I store values into SharedPreferences in one activity:

```
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String firstPlace = new String("1");
        String secondPlace = new String("2");
        String thirdPlace = new String("3");

        editor = sharedPref.edit();

        editor.putString("first", firstPlace);
        editor.putString("second", secondPlace);
        editor.putString("third", thirdPlace);
        editor.commit();
```

And try to retrieve them in another activity. However, the retrieve doesn't seem to be getting the values I put in and is just using the defaults (so "1st Place: " "2nd Place: " and "3rd Place: " end up with a 'no' next to them).

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

    String firstPlace = sharedPref.getString("first", "no");
    String secondPlace = sharedPref.getString("second", "no");
    String thirdlace = sharedPref.getString("third", "no");

    highScore1.setText("1st Place: " + firstPlace);
    highScore2.setText("2nd Place: " + secondPlace);
    highScore3.setText("3rd Place: " + thirdlace);
```

Comment: Can you also add the code where Editor object is created?

Comment: Try  `.apply()`  than  `.commit()`

Comment: That's pretty much all I do with the editor... I have it as a global variable at the top "    "SharedPreferences.Editor editor;" and then I do the "editor = sharedPref.edit();" as you see in the first block of code. Is there more I have to do to it?

Comment: You seem to be using different contexts. Not sure if that matters, though

Comment: @Freckles your code seems fine. If by some reason you are unable to retrieve the value, I would see whether they are saved in the actual xml file which can be found in /root/data/data/your.app.package/shared_pref/sharedPref.xml (note that this requires root). Alternatively, you can use my [SharedPreferences library](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/ORMPreferences) which could ease up things for you.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36856455/5733111) ..
By doing so it will ease the LOC

Comment: @Hendra Anggrian thanks! I guess I can't do that in looking at the project folder structure on the side of Android Studio, huh. How do I access that path? Command line? Sorry, new to all of this ^_^;

Comment: did your problem solved or not

Comment: @Freckles to access that directory, you would need your Android device to be rooted. If you are unwilling to root your device then you could use pre-rooted emulator like Genymotion. Once rooted, you may access it by command line or third-party file manager app that supports root access like ES File Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to direct put value

```
    editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("first", "1");
    editor.putString("second", "2");
    editor.putString("third", "3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used separate contexts. To make your sharedpreference accesible to entire application you need default sharedpreference. Declare it as below

```
   SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

After this you can edit and fetch data as you did before.

Comment: I personally believe using different contexts could not be the issue. SharedPreferences files do not differ each context, they are stored per app package.

Comment: Yes, I tried using DefaultSharedPreferences and it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

please try this,

`this.SharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
           SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = this.SharedPrefs.edit();
            localEditor.putString("first", firstPlace);
            localEditor.putString("second", secondPlace);
            localEditor.putString("third", thirdPlace);
            localEditor.commit();
            finish();`