# Key-Value Store Data not retrieved

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my app, I am trying to save a key value as zero or one depending on whether a checkbox is checked. I retrieve these values in a different activity. However, when I attempt to retrieve the value, I am getting an empty string:

Saving key values in Activity 1(ScienceCoursesCheck):

```
public void setDefaults(String key, String value) {
   SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
   editor.putString(key, value);
   editor.commit();

}
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
   // Is the view now checked?
   boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

   // Check which checkbox was clicked
   switch(view.getId()) {
       case R.id.checkBox_APBio:
           if (checked) {
               setDefaults("APBio", "1");
           }
           else {
               setDefaults("APBio", "0");
               break;
           }
}}
```

Retrieving key values in activity 2(MyHome):

```
public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {
   SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   return preferences.getString(key, null);
}

public void myMethod() {
   SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("ScienceCoursesCheck", MODE_PRIVATE);  
   String APBio = myPrefs.getString("APBio","");
   if (APBio.equals("1")){
       Button myButton = new Button(this);
       myButton.setText(APBio);
       RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_home);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       ll.addView(myButton, lp);
   }
  }
```

Is the second activity accessing the correct SharedPreferences file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code for sharedpreference. Call

> Util.saveInfo(activityContext,_key,_value)

when you want to save the info. Then call

> Util.getInfo(getApplicationContext(),_key)

to get the info.

```
public class Util{
public static void saveInfo(Context context, String key, String value )
{
    try
    {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString(key, value).apply();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG," saveInfo "+ex+"");
    }
}
public static String getInfo(Context context, String key)
{
    try {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(key,"");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because when you store the items in `SharedPreferences` you are using

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences
```

but when you retrieve them you are using

```
getSharedPreferences("ScienceCoursesCheck", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

These are two different `SharedPreferences` files. Try using `getSharedPreferences("ScienceCoursesCheck", MODE_PRIVATE);` for your setting method as well. Or perhaps you meant to use your `getDefaults()` method in `activity 2` instead of `myPrefs`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are saving in the `DefaultSharedPreferences` file

```
   SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

and retrieving from another file named `"ScienceCoursesCheck"`

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("ScienceCoursesCheck", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and they are not the same file!

See the difference between `getSharedPreferences` and `getDefaultSharedPreferences` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310080/5993410)

====

**Solution** is either to always use `DefaultSharedPreferences` OR always use the file named `"ScienceCoursesCheck"` .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're saving the values in the **DefaultSharedPreference** and trying to retrieve the values from the `ScienceCoursesCheck` preference file.

Try below code for `setDefaults` method.The [getDefaultSharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)) and [getSharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getSharedPreferences()) methods are different.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946135/difference-between-getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-getsharedpreferences) for the difference.

```
 public void setDefaults(String key, String value) {
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getDefaultSharedPreferences("ScienceCoursesCheck", MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
       editor.putString(key, value);
       editor.commit();

    }
```

Hope this helps you...